# Access-Control-Allow-Origin while accessing

Tags: angularjs, django, rest, django-models, django-forms

I am facing a problem of Access-Control-Allow-Origin while accessing from Angular JS, How should I fix this error with POST Request.

Please Provide me a solution to access or Insert data with POST request in Angular JS, Now I m fine with GET request to access cross domain but not with POST Request

Backend is developed in python Django

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Would you please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and provide some of your own code, expected behavior and problem description. StackOverflow are no _solution provider_ service.

Answer (score 2):

Ask your backend(python django) developer to configure [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers)

> A Django App that adds CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) headers to responses.

It's the best solution I have got so far. It'll allow cross origin requests.